# Problems using Matlab function eps2pdf

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab script where I produce a figure, and then create an eps file in my current directory using the command
print('myFile','-depsc'). Immediately following, I have: mypdf = eps2pdf('myFile').

I get the error message that 'Error while creating temporary eps file: ..... cannot be accessed or does not exist'.

Has anyone had a similar problem?  Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong?  I'm using Ubuntu and Matlab 2017a.

---

Here is an example code that I type into the command line.  I get the error message which I stated above.

---

```
figure()
plot(linspace(1,100),linspace(1,100)) %Simple line
print('my_plot','-depsc')  %Create eps file.
mypdf = eps2pdf('my_plot'); %Should produce mypdf in my current directory.
<error message prints>
```

---

Comment: Please add some more code as per my comments.

Comment: Step 1: do you have a file called “myFile” in the current directory? Are you sure it’s not “myFile.eps”?

Comment: In my current directory: myFile.eps

Comment: Did you try `eps2pdf('myFile.eps')` instead of `eps2pdf('myFile')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a standard function. If you read the function you will see errStr that it returns for this.

```
function [ok,errStr] = read_epsfilecontent( epsFile )
% Reads the content of the eps file into epsFileContent
global epsFileContent

ok = 0;
errStr = [];
fh = fopen(epsFile,'r');
if fh == -1
    errStr = ['File: ' epsFile ' cannot be accessed or does not exist'];
    return
end
```

Then we figure out when fopen returns -1

> fileID = fopen(filename) opens the file, filename, for binary read
>   access, and returns an integer file identifier equal to or greater
>   than 3. MATLAB® reserves file identifiers 0, 1, and 2 for standard
>   input, standard output (the screen), and standard error, respectively.
>
> If fopen cannot open the file, then fileID is -1.

Which means please post some of your code so we can figure out why it cannot open your file.

Edit: After some work around and it wasn't necessary to download the code this is how I solved your problem. There is another implementation called [eps2xxx](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6858-eps2xxx?focused=5058445&tab=function)
While running your code I received this error

> Error while creating temporary eps file: *.eps - File:
>   C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\MATLAB*.eps cannot be accessed or does not
>   exist

Which lead me to the information in the documentation here.

```
% Create tmp file,...
[ok,errStr] = create_tmpepsfile(source,tmpFile,orientation);
if ~ok
    status = ['Error while creating temporary eps file: ' epsFile ' - ' errStr];
    if nargout,      result = 1;    end;
    if nargout > 1,  msg = status;  else, disp(status); end;
```

And I read you needed GhostScript, I wasn't sure if I had this anyways. I downloaded it and gave the full pathway to GS like the following.

```
figure()
fullgspath = 'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.23\bin\gswin64c.exe';
plot(linspace(1,100),linspace(1,100)); %Simple line
print('my_plot','-depsc');
eps2xxx('my_plot.eps',{'pdf'},fullgspath);
```

which created your nice little pdf here.[image]

Comment: I added a simple code to my question post.  Thanks.

Comment: edited it works, it doesn't necessarily need eps2xxx however it may need the full GS pathway I believe.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for solving this for me.